# Set file created/modified timestamp to the earlier of the 2 for a ton of files?

Tags: macos, terminal, finder, applescript, automator

I searched for an answer to this for a while, but couldn't find one. I have a lot of wav files (thousands of them) in a sound library that somehow got either the modification or creation date updated very recently, even though I haven't touched them in any way for years.

Is there some way I could use Automator to make an application that I could drag & drop these files to (or a text file containing all of their paths & filenames) that would do the following?:

- Check the timestamp data associated with the file
  (date/time: modified, and created)
- Check to see which timestamp is the earlier of the two
- If the created timestamp is earlier than the modified one, change the modified timestamp to the created, or vice versa.

I know how to get the date modified or created in terminal, and how to loop through the files received as input. But I'm not sure how to ***compare*** the timestamps in a script to determine which is earlier, or how specifically to format the script/app that would do this automatically for each file.

I got the following script from another thread. But this will just set the date modified to the date created without checking to see which one is earlier.

```
for f in *.wav; do
   olddate=$(stat -f %SB -t %Y%m%d%H%M "$f")
   touch -m -t $olddate "$f"    
done
```

And in case it makes a difference, I'm on a MacBook Pro running macOS Sierra 10.12.6.

Lastly, if this would be more appropriate for a different network (stackoverflow or superuser maybe), please LMK and I'll ask there instead.

Thank you in advance for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *example* **shell script** *code*, show below, uses `GetFileInfo` and `SetFile` from **Command Line Tools for Xcode**, which the latter is needed to change the *creation date*, as `touch` can only change the *access* and *modification* times.

If you do not have **Xcode** installed, then just install the **Command Line Tools for Xcode**...

In Terminal: `xcode-select --install`

After installing **Command Line Tools for Xcode**, then in **Automator** you can create a *workflow* or *Service/Quick Action* with the appropriate *actions* to pass the target *files* to a **Run Shell Script** *action* with settings **Shell: [/bin/bash]** and **Pass input: [as arguments]** using the following *example* **shell script** *code*:

```bash
for f in "$@"; do

    [ -f "$f" ] || continue

    c="$(GetFileInfo -d "$f")"
    m="$(GetFileInfo -m "$f")"

    ec="$(date -j -f "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S" "$c" +%s)"
    em="$(date -j -f "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S" "$m" +%s)"

    if [ "$ec" -lt "$em" ]; then
        SetFile -m "$c" "$f"
    fi

    if [ "$em" -lt "$ec" ]; then
        SetFile -d "$m" "$f"
    fi

done
```

---

How the *shell script* works:

- `for f in "$@"; do` -- For each *file* do *something*.
- `[ -f "$f" ] || continue` -- If it's not a *file*, then go to the next *item* passed.
- `c="$(GetFileInfo -d "$f")"` -- Gets the *creation date* of the *file*.
- `m="$(GetFileInfo -m "$f")"` -- Gets the *modification date* of the *file*.
- `ec="$(date -j -f "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S" "$c" +%s)"` -- Converts the *creation date* to the number *seconds* since **Epoch**.
- `em="$(date -j -f "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S" "$m" +%s)"` -- Converts the *modification date* to the number *seconds* since **Epoch**.
- `if [ "$ec" -lt "$em" ]; then` -- If the **Epoch** *creation date seconds* is less than the **Epoch** *modification date seconds*, then:

  - `SetFile -m "$c" "$f"` -- Sets the *modification date* of the *file* to the *creation date* of the *file*.
- `if [ "$em" -lt "$ec" ]; then` -- If the **Epoch** *modification date seconds* is less than the **Epoch** *creation date seconds*, then:

  - `SetFile -d "$m" "$f"` -- Sets the *creation date* of the *file* to the *modification date* of the *file*.

---

**Notes:**

**Epoch** (00:00:00 UTC, January 1, 1970; see time(3).

---

Example **Automator** *workflow*:

Just add the parent *folder* containing the **.wav** *files* to the **Get Specified Finder Items** *action* and set the rest of the *actions* as shown in the image below.

Note that this is just an example, the main part is the **Run Shell Script** *action*, so however you want to pass the target *files* to it is your choice.

[image]

Comment: Hey I just tried this for a folder, and it didn't work. Is there something I could change so that it would also work for folders to change date modified to the earlier of the two (created or modified)?

Comment: @Max Well, RE: "Hey I just tried this for a folder, and it didn't work. " --  Well that to be expected as it's filtering for **wav** _files_ not _folders_ and as described in 'How the _shell script_ works:' if it's not a _file_ it doesn't process it. You need to change the **Automator** _workflow_ to pass _folders_ to the **Run Shell Script** _action_ and remove the _test_ for _files_ in the **Run Shell Script** _action_.

Comment: Actually, I set up the automator workflow to receive files & folders as input, and pass them to bin/bash shell as arguments, so that I could use it for other files as well. It just wouldn't work for a folder when I passed that to it. But it looks like commenting out the line "[ -f "$f" ] || continue" worked. Thank you again! :)